# I have to multiply the digits as well as adding them.,

Tags: mips32

```
.data

enterMsg1: .asciiz "Please enter the last four digits of your student id \n"
enterMsg2: .asciiz "Press enter between each digit \n"
enterMsg3: .asciiz "Enter next digit \n"
TotalDig4: .asciiz "The total of the digits is: "
.text

# output the initial instruction text to the console
addi $v0, $zero, 4
la $a0, enterMsg1
syscall

# output the second instruction text to the console
addi $v0, $zero, 4
la $a0, enterMsg2
syscall


# read an integer from keyboard input and store the input in $s0 for the total
addi $v0, $zero, 5
syscall
# store the input in $s0
add $s0, $zero, $v0


# output the text asking for the next digit to the console
# then receive the input,
jal receiveInputs
 #add to total ($s0)
add $s0, $s0, $v0

# then receive the input,
jal receiveInputs
 #add to total ($s0)
add $s0, $s0, $v0

# then receive the input,
jal receiveInputs
 #add to total ($s0)
add $s0, $s0, $v0

# output the total text to the console
addi $v0, $zero, 4
la $a0, TotalDig4
syscall


add $a0, $s0, $zero
addi $v0, $zero, 1
syscall


addi $v0, $zero, 10
syscall

receiveInputs:
# receive the input, add to total ($s0)
addi $v0, $zero, 4
la $a0, enterMsg3
syscall

addi $v0, $zero, 5
syscall

jr $ra

Loop:
add $s0, $zero, $s0
addi $a0, $zero, 1
syscall

# output a space 
addi $v0, $zero, 10
addi $a0, $zero, 0x20
syscall

addi $s0, $s0, -1


# end the program
addi $v0, $zero, 10
```

Comment: what is your question? ... do you have a problem of some kind?

Comment: this the code I am working on it. and I have to multiply the digits. this code when I run it is adding the last four digits of the id number. but ineed to add code to multiply them as well

Answer (score 1):

After adding the first digit to `$s0`, on the next line add that same first digit from `$v0` to `$s1` which will hold your product.

Then after getting each digit from the function `receiveInputs` use `(mul $s1, $s1, $v0)` to multiply the digits.

Finally print the result from `$s1` just as you would for the sum.